# in spinner items display the list array to replace drawable images how can implemented

Tags: android

i am using spinner in some application  in spinner item list array  this text replaced in drawable images  how can its implemented

```
personalinformation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerCategory);
ArrayAdapter<?> adapterDefaultpersonal = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Animals.this, R.array.Animalinformation, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapterDefaultpersonal.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
personalinformation.setAdapter(adapterDefaultpersonal);
```

How can the `R.array.Animalinformation` array list items replaced in drawable images be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is look at the code below..
array of data

```
//stores the image database icons 
 private static Integer[] imageIconDatabase = { R.drawable.ball, R.drawable.catmouse,   R.drawable.cube, R.drawable.fresh, R.drawable.guitar, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.teapot };

//stores the image database names 
 private String[] imageNameDatabase = { "ball", "catmouse", "cube", "fresh", "guitar", "orange", "teapot" };
```

---

creating List of hashmaps

```
private void initializeImageList() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> spinnerList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < imageNameDatabase.length; i++) {
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("Name", imageNameDatabase[i]);         
    map.put("Icon", imageIconDatabase[i]);         
    spinnerList.add(map);     
    }     
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);     
imageView.setBackgroundResource((spinnerList.get(0).get("Icon"));     
spinnerList.get(0).get("Name"); 
}

// assigning spinner to adapter

public void createAddDialog() { // TODO
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_editoradd_dialog);

    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAddImageList);
    CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, spinnerData, R.layout.spinner_view, new String[] { "Name", "Icon" }, new int[] { R.id.imageNameSpinner, R.id.imageIconSpinner });
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

the adapter used above is as given below..

```
class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> dataRecieved;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    dataRecieved = data;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{     
    if (convertView == null) { 
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_view,null);
        } 
HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);    
((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageNameSpinner)).setText((String) dataRecieved.get(position).get("Name"));
((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageIconSpinner)).setBackgroundResource(dataRecieved.get(position).get("Icon")));
return convertView; 
}
}
```

Comment: Ur welcome and sorry for the bad editing.I have tried improving it as much as possible.